# Understanding proxy_cache_bypass $http_cache_control

Tags: nginx

According to [Nginx's doc](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_bypass) on `proxy_cache_bypass`

> Defines conditions under which the response will not be taken from a cache. If at least one value of the string parameters is not empty and is not equal to “0” then the response will not be taken from the cache:

I want the request with the header `Cache-Control: no-cache` to bypass the Nginx cache and be forwarded to the upstream service. Shall I use the following config?

```
proxy_cache_bypass $http_cache_control;
```

I asked because it seems Nginx will bypass the cache whenever the `Cache-Control` has non-zero value without checking if its content is `no-cache`. If not, what would be the best way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. You should use a `map` to [select the correct value](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) to control the cache.

For example:

```
map $http_cache_control $cache_bypass {
    no-cache   1;
}

proxy_cache_bypass $cache_bypass;
```

*Note that the `map` block must be placed outside of the `server` block.*